# Simple question how to see javadoc in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

When I hover over any SWT objekt in Eclipse I get this:

[image]

I have downloaded jar files that say they are SWT javadoc from Eclipse website and attached them to:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I go to Eclipse website and download this eclipse-jee-2020-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip , that's the Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers 400MB full suit

Comment: I believe you need the "sources" and not the Javadoc.

Comment: I agree with @C.Weber to the extent that your dialog box says it is configuring a location for source instead of Javadoc. In my version of eclipse, under build path configuration, under Libaries, when I've clicked on an individual library, there is one place to enter a source location and another to enter a javadoc location. I have not played with these to see, but suspect that if all you want is for javadoc for the library to pop up when you hover, the javadoc location may be enough. You would need source if you wanted to compile with the debug flag and step through the library source...

Comment: Thanks all, I tried adding to source also like [this](https://snipboard.io/DkeYWZ.jpg) I got that jar from [here](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.16-202006040540/#SWT)

Comment: The screenshot shows, that you tried to add the Javadoc (`...-javadoc.jar`) instead of the source (`src.zip`) as source. In the shown dialog, you have to add the source, not the Javadoc.

Comment: I tried also the src.zip that was inside and even unzipping it but does not work. I download the [SWT Binary and Source](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.16-202006040540/#SWT) zip file that is named; swt-4.16-win32-win32-x86_64.zip I try to add it [like this](https://snipboard.io/fSg6Yr.jpg), even added it to source as image show

Comment: I read something about that javadoc is included and work out-of-the box in Eclipse so I think my installation is broken

Comment: [Follow the instructions given here](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/eclipse.php). That you have JARs of the `plugins` folder of Eclipse on the  Java Build Path looks odd in this case.

Comment: @Howlger Thanks I try can you say were this zip file is I mean there are so many "First, download the .zip of SWT for your platform from the SWT homepage."

Comment: You have already downloaded the correct ZIP file: _"SWT Binary and Source zip file that is named; swt-4.16-win32-win32-x86_64.zip"_.